# Asking Duplicate questions from SciFi to gain movie perspective

Tags: discussion, scope, exact-duplicates

As far as I understand, cross posts between SciFi and movies are allowed [SciFi/Movies overlap](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/scifi-movies-overlap/404#404)

Though, I have recently found out that this is not the case when the user posting the duplicate is aware of what he is doing.

So are all questions already posted on SciFi now officially not allowed/frowned upon when posted on Movies? Isn't the point of asking on Movies to get an analysis/explanation within the film domain and not the range of the entire SciFi topic for that movie?

If so, then it shouldn't matter what the user does.
If not, what are we doing here?

Duplicates across sites cannot decrease the expertise if looking from two different concepts.

Comment: This is a network wide policy as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a case-by-case issue to analyze here.

First case is a new user to SE as a whole, finds M&TV.SE and posts a question about a sci-fi movie.  From there, they find our Sci-Fi.SE site and decides "Hey, I'm going to get the most I can out of this and post the **same exact question** here too!

- This situation should be dealt by the moderators of the sites, collaborating to find out which site the question is *more* On-Topic for.  You then close the other one and both mods instruct the user to not perform this behavior.

Second case is a new user to M&TV.SE has **NO** interest in Sci-Fi.SE, has no idea this existed and asks a **similar, possibly same** question on M&TV.SE that has been asked on Sci-fi.SE before.

- **This is perfectly OK**.

I don't expect people, especially new users, to search Sci-fi.SE far and wide to see if their question has been asked before posting it on M&TV.SE (though, I do expect them to search *our site* before posting).  If someone wants to inform the user that it has been asked before on Sci-fi.SE, go right ahead.  If that user is interested in those answers, even wants their question closed because they found the answer, then so be it.

However, should they want a different perspective from a site that focuses on *just the movie universe* or something that doesn't have to be about expanded universes, etc and want answers from *our* community, that is OK as well.

---

In this case you are talking about, the user has been told *many* times by myself **and** Sci-Fi.SE mods to *not* cross post their questions.

---

Not only what I said above, [it is also a policy of [**Stack Exchange**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) as a whole.

---

To be as clear as I can be:

- **Overlap is fine**.
- Deliberately cross-posting is **not** fine

Comment: Yup, this is how I had interpreted things.

Comment: [K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_K)

Comment: +1 - I for myself am not an active member of the SciFi.SE site. If I have a question about a SciFi movie, I'm not gonna look there as it is perfectly on topic here.

Answer (score 4):

To add, if someone posts a question on sci-fi, then modifies it signifigantly and wants a different answer from movies, then I'm ok with the "cross post".

For example, let's say that someone asks a question about Spider-man.  On Sci-fi they'll get a canonical answer from all of spider-man's history.  They then ask a similer question on movies, but with the intention of only including the spider-man movies.  This, to me, is signifigant enough to warrent leaving it open.