# Is SciFi the reason for Movies SE still being in beta?

Tags: discussion

I know that there is bound to be some overlap between sites on SE but there is an unusual amount of overlap between SE and Movies. My main problem is that clearly movie oriented questions appear on SciFi instead of Movies. Isnt this affecting Movies moving out of beta? Can something be done regarding this?

Now, this is nothing against the SciFi site. I am a regular visitor and tend to find really good answers to scifi related questions there.

[Edit]

Just to be clear, my concern is largely towards losing questions to SciFi and as a consequence visits/day and user count.

I was able to find the following questions which obviously fit on the Movies & TV SE just on the first page of the SciFi site.

[AT-ST at the Battle of Hoth in the original version of Episode V?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76085/at-st-at-the-battle-of-hoth-in-the-original-version-of-episode-v)

[Transformers: Age of Extinction background music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69251/transformers-age-of-extinction-background-music)

[Movie about attacking Roots/Giant Plant?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76073/movie-about-attacking-roots-giant-plant)

[Why didn't the 11th Doctor recognize River Song?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/why-didnt-the-11th-doctor-recognize-river-song)

Comment: I'm not sure what this would have to do with still being in beta. Do you mean the SE team is actively ignoring the site because they don't find it necessary? Seems unlikely. Of course we lose many question to a site where even the *Dark Knight* trilogy is counted as SciFi, but I don't think that plays a role in the suspended graduation (even if the progress thereof is largely untransparent and might invite such theories).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: My point was towards losing questions to SciFi. Nothing to do with the SE team of course.

Comment: But given that we're already slated for graduation and are effectively only waiting for the design to finish, it seems unlikely to be dependent on the number of questions either. But who knows, the fact there's no progress made is surely not working against user emigration.

Comment: "we're already slated for graduation" - oh, I didn't know this. Kinda' makes this question pretty weak. Oh well...

Comment: Then you clearly didn't do your homework. Really, [that question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1471/49) is 2 days old and listed 3rd after yours on the front page.

Comment: Well, maybe I can rephrase it to why it took us this long :) Any idea how long SciFi was in beta?

Comment: *"maybe I can rephrase it to why it took us this long"* - Well, the other question asks this already afterall. I understand that SciFi.SE competition is a major problem, but it's a natural consequence we have to live with and we shouldn't make too much out of it. As much as I understood is that the SE design team is the limiting factor currenty, there are multiple sites waiting for their design already. That being said, we were slated for graduation after about 800 days in beta, which I think isn't too long at all (those 90 days from the docs are practically rubbish anyway, it's a lower bound)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: When was the last time anything came out of Beta within a year? Any idea?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander it can be said diffrently that Scifi is loosing question because of us? or anime.se?

Comment: Anyways we have discussed Scifi vs M&Tv so many time that, there is no more points left to say.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: SciFi is not the one in beta.

Comment: Sci-Fi have repeatedly stated that they will not migrate questions to us which are more "on-topic" over here, unless they are entirely off topic there... they won't migrate to a Beta unless they absolutely need to..

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional And this is related to which of the standpoints here?

Comment: @AndrewMartin and bobbyalex: SciFi came out of beta within about a year.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a large number of questions addressing the overlap between 'Science Fiction & Fantasy' and 'Movies & TV' sites.  I'm not going to list all the relevant ones here, but this one is probably the most general and worth restating:

[SciFi/Movies overlap](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/scifi-movies-overlap/404#404)

The overlap between the sites is not considered a particular problem by StackExchange. Some overlap between sites like this is inevitable, and it would be fruitless to attempt to manage the scope in such a way that more questions come to this site.  It would be confusing and harmful to either site to have confusing rules like .... "you can ask all questions about scifi *except* those about tv and movies, or "you can ask all questions about tv and movies, *except* science fiction".

We have been informed that we have met the criteria for graduation to a full site, and that the only thing hampering this is the backlog of site-design work.

Comment: The difficulty here is when people are asking about details of a TV/Movie franchise and want to know *details about the source material*, we migrate to Sci-Fi... when they get asked questions about the TV/Movie adaptation only (and not book material), they refuse to migrate to us... I tried to initiate an understanding some time ago on their beta, and was verbally lynched for the attempt...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional No, we don't. If the question is adressing the movie to *some* degree it's perfectly on-topic here. And sorry to not let it rest, but *you weren't lynched the slightest* for attempting to initiate that understanding, only for misunderstanding their reaction and refusing to accept that they simply couldn't understand you, falling into quite a defensive and indignant attitude as a reaction (and granted, for that you might indeed have been "lynched", but who wouldn't).